# Apllication using flex 4.5 and native api of iPhone, Android and Balckberry

Tags: iphone, android, flex4.5

One can create iPhone, android and Balckberry playbook app using Flex 4.5. Is there any any difference or performance issue between the native app and and the app created using flex 4.5? Please suggest where to use and where to use native API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Nipin here that for BB/Android it would work fine, but for iOS go native. The primary issue with iOS is performance. If you have a really simple app, it might work okay, but you can not write a complex app in ActionScript/Flex 4.5.1 that performs even close to what a native iOS app would. There are some things you can do to make your app perform better on iOS, but it just isn't there. If you do want to go the cross-compile route, my recommendation is to write ActionScript whenever you can and avoid Flex as AS can be customized much more and is just faster/more efficient to run in general for anything of higher complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference in native app and a flex converted app,in case of blackberry and android,but for ios my recommendation is u must create native app for ios.There are some issues in flex ios app.Flex support better in Android and blackberry.

Comment: Thanx, But why? Can tell what kind issue people are facing incase of iPhone and iOS

Comment: @Kamahire ,yhe main issue is application crash during thr run time ,memmory issues like that,i strongely reccomend to go for native in case of ios.If the answer is useful for you please accept this .